# Is it possible to manipulate data frame by column name and number?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I'm working on large data set, about 900 columns. i have something like this:

```
B <- c(1)
A_1 <- c(2)
A_2 <- c(3)
A_3 <- c(7)
A_4 <- c(9)
df <- data.frame(B,A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4)
```

I would like to be able to do something like this :

```
df[,A_1:A_1+3]
```

Do you know if it's possible ?

I'm also working with data.table so if there is a way with data.table it could be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base R's `subset` will let you do this.

```
subset(mtcars, , mpg:(mpg + 1))
#                     mpg cyl
#Mazda RX4           21.0   6
#Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6
#Datsun 710          22.8   4
#Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6
#Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8
#...
```

dplyr's `select` works the same way.

Comment: the thing is that i don't want to write the ending column's name

Comment: For completeness and because you mentioned it in the OP, @Orhan , `library(data.table); setDT(df)[, A_1:(A_1+3)]` works (though I wasn't expecting it to).

Comment: nice thank you, it also usefull because i'm often working with data.table =)